# Find a number is even or odd

Tags: c

I want to write a program to print a number is odd or even. I can't do this:
1) use if or while or do or switch
2) use ?: operator
3) arrays
It is possible because it is our question. We want to show "Even" or "Odd" in our printf without if.
Is it possible to help me?

Answer from my assistant:

```
int main()
{
    int number, answer;
    printf("Please Enter first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    (number % 2 && printf("odd")) || printf("even");
}
```

my assistant said that there is another way too. He will give it to us. I will post it too.
Thanks everyone for answers and information.

Comment: Your question is not really specific to C.

Comment: @Amin Borjian  It seems using an if statement and the conditional operator in the same program contradicts each other.

Comment: Where is your specific problem? What have you tried so far? Please provide a [minmal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: int IsEvenOrOdd(int input){return 1;}

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? How did your attempt work or not work? Can you show us your attempt? And yes, it's definitely possible to do.

Comment: I think we can figure something out that works, but why not show us what you've done so far?

Comment: `printf("a number is odd or even");`

Comment: I can understand a number is odd or even but when I want to display it, I have to use if for correct print but I don't have permission for this.

Comment: Why don't you have permission to print?

Comment: Have a look at the `switch` statement.

Comment: switch is same as if. we can't use it too. it's our question!

Comment: So.. if you cannot use switch, arrays, what can you use? Now seriously, would you please be kind to edit the question and specify in details what you want to do?

Comment: `int odd = even_or_odd_int & 1; printf("%d is %c%c%c%c.\n", even_or_odd_int, 'e' + odd * ('o' - 'e'), 'v' + odd * ('d' - 'v'), 'e' + odd * ('d' - 'e'), 'n' + odd * (' ' - 'n'));` :-)

Answer (score 3):

One approach could be check if the least significant bit is lit, and use it as an index of an array of hard-coded strings "even" and "odd":

```
int number = /* some number */;
char* descriptions[2];
descriptions[0] = "even";
descriptions[1] = "odd";

printf("%d is %s\n", number, descriptions[number & 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but  I forget. We can't use array too.

Comment: This solution fails if `number` is negative (it results in an index of -1, so it indexes out of bounds).  It's easily fixed by replacing `% 2` with `& 1`.

Comment: @TomKarzes Nice catch, thanks! I incorporated that to my answer.